# how to move the cmap.set_bad setting to PIL

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I provide here an example of what I am doing.
I need to create a map with nodata value included, and I decided to have them in red color so:

```
from PIL import Image

import matplotlib.cm as cm

current_cmap = cm.YlGn

current_cmap.set_bad(color = 'red')
```

Then I have numpy array (image) to display and I move to PIL with this :

```
img = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(current_cmap(data)*255))

img.show()
```

The image comes out with the proper colormap, but the nodata values are still with the default setting, not the one I chose at the beginning. How can it be modified in PIL?

I attach here two image to explain my question :

[image]

this is the map obtained with matplotlib, I have set the nodata with red color

And now the other one obtained via PIL, with the same colormap:

[image]

_It is clear that where I chose the red color, the colormap in this case has maintained the white color. I don't know why my setting is not working for it

Comment: One cannot know for sure because `data` in unknown in the question, but I suppose you haven't defined nodata correctly. (see [mcve])

Comment: I don't think the pictures will help anyone finding out what's wrong as long as we don't know anything about `data` and `nodata`. Again, see [mcve] (most probably a small hardcoded array of size 4 x 4 would work)

Comment: I suspect somebody on StackOverflow can help you, if you improve the code that loads the image and sets up the bad data, so you know what to do....